# FIPS 140-2 Compliant Algorithms

Tags: encryption, signature, fips-140

Is there any reference to check the list of encryption & signing algorithms which are compliant to FIPS 140-2. After an exhaustive search I could find only "AES".

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Siva, FYI - SHA1 for certificate use has been deprecated by the industry. Any new certificates generated should use a stronger hashing algorithm.

Comment: @SakthiKumaranSuriya for FIPS compliance, SHA-1 has been deprecated as of 2010 for most uses

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a look at [FIPS 140-2 Annex A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexa.pdf). It lists the following:

- Symmetric Key

  - AES, Triple-DES, Escrowed Encryption Standard
- Asymmetric Key

  - DSA, RSA, ECDSA
- Hash Standards

  - SHA-1, SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512, SHA-512/224, SHA-512/256
- Random number generators

  - See [annex c](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexc.pdf)
- Message authentication

  - CCM, GCM, GMAC, CMAC, HMAC

Comment: What about DES?

Comment: The FIPS 140-2 states that approved security function is either specified in the list of approved functions (which annex A is), or specified in a Federal Information Processing Standard(FIPS).  The DES is specified in FIPS. However FIPS 140-2 Implementation Guide states that DES is not approved since May 19, 2007.  
And looking at the List of FIPS-140 validated modules I can see that DES is listed only in *other algorithms* section.
However, Microsoft .Net Framework doesn't thrown an exception if you try to use DES when FIPS policy is forced (as it does with other non-approved algorithms).

Comment: @mistika Original/single DES (formally DEA) *was* specified by FIPS 46, through several revisions, but 46-3 was withdrawn in 2005, see http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsFIPSArch.html . "Triple-DES" or "3DES" (formally TDEA) *only*, *not* single-DES, was reissued as a special publication (SP800-67) -- and that SP is referenced by current 140-2 IG and 140-2 annex A.

Comment: the FIPS document is a draft

Comment: In the approved modes there is ECB in, SP 800-38A, why is that even if it's not recommended by the security community ?

Comment: Any idea about key exchange algorithms e.g for openssh client ?

Comment: Per this post and the references it provides, I switched a web application from Rijndale to AES and the FIPS errors from ASP.NET / IIS ceased.

Comment: You also need to look at Annex D, which lists "Key Establishment Techniques". That contains RSA _encryption_ (OAEP or KEM), Diffie-Hellman, PBKDF2 etc. For FIPS 140-3 the reference appears to be [NIST SP 800-140Cr1 ](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-140Cr1.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The current list of FIPS-approved cryptographical methods is [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexa.pdf).

For encryption, we're limited to AES, 3DES (known as TDEA in FIPS-speak), and EES (Skipjack).

As for signing algorithms, we have RSA, DSA and ECDSA.

Note that the list of FIPS-approved algorithms does change at times; not extremely frequently, but more often than they come out with a new version of FIPS 140.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no FIPS 140-2 approved asymmetric encryption algorithm, as DSA/RSA/ECDSA are only approved for key generation/signature.

Comment: My understanding is that RSA can be used to encrypt a symmetric key, so you then perform a (standard) hybrid encryption.  TBH, you really have to do this anyway with RSA.